# ftp php file uploadin

Tags: php

```
<?php
   ini_set('max_execution_time', '0');

   $host = '234.546.155.485';
   $usr = 'fgfgfgdf';
   $pwd = 'fghghh';

   // file to move:
   $file = 'http://vsomesite.com/file.flv';
   $ftp_path = '/public_html/video57242/test.flv';

   // connect to FTP server (port 21)
   $conn_id = ftp_connect($host, 21) or die ("Cannot connect to host");

   // send access parameters
   ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd) or die("Cannot login");

   // turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
   // ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

   // perform file upload
   $upload = ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $file, FTP_ASCII);

   // check upload status:
   print (!$upload) ? 'Cannot upload' : 'Upload complete';
   ?>
```

upload fails when the file is remote not local. what problem?

Comment: Please post the code that retrieves the remote file so that ftp_put() can actually upload it (presumably `$local_file`)

Comment: @Issak, no, it doesn't. It only uploads local files. What may be confusing you is that it lets you specify the remote path where you want to place the uploaded local file.

Comment: then how would i transfer files from one server to another server with the help of php.

Comment: I just checked, an FLV file is definitely binary, as per Atli's point.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Your variables don't add up. You use `$local_file` in your `ftp_put()` call, but you only declare `$file` earlier in the script</strike>

And are you sure you should be using `FTP_ASCII` for a FLV file? I'd have thought that was binary.

**Edit**
Scratch my first point. Seems you edited it away :)